# How to set code syntax highlight using angular-marked

Tags: angularjs, highlight.js

I use [angular-marked](https://github.com/Hypercubed/angular-marked) in my website. And I want highlight code in markdown. I read the Readme docs, in the [set default options optional](https://github.com/Hypercubed/angular-marked#set-default-options-optional) section, when I use the code in my project

```
markedProvider.setOptions({
  gfm: true,
  tables: true,
  highlight: function (code) {
    return hljs.highlightAuto(code).value;
  }
});
```

and I have added highlight.js and .css references, according the [Highlight.js doc](https://highlightjs.org/download/)

but Jshint complain **'hljs' not defined**. Please help me, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

have you include the highlight js file before `setOptions` ?

Here is my code (using requirejs and angularAMD)

```
define([
    'app',
    'hljs',
    'services/srv.post',
    'angular-marked'
], function (app, hljs) {
    app.config(['markedProvider', function(markedProvider) {
        markedProvider.setOptions({
            gfm: true,
            tables: true,
            highlight: function (code, lang, callback) {
                return hljs.highlightAuto(code).value;
            }
        });
    }]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe hljs is already been imported after you added the highlight.js. The problem you have is the jshint detect the hljs is not defined within the current file, but after browser load every script, the hljs will be available. You can suppress this alarm in the jshintrc by adding 
`"globals": {
    "hdls": false,
  }`